# Import Error after pip install -e

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have cloned a repo ([visdom](https://github.com/facebookresearch/visdom)) from github in order to make some contributions. In order to test my contributions, I tried to install the module within a conda env:

```
$ which pip
/home/jkarimi91/Apps/anaconda2/envs/visdom/bin/pip
$ pip install -e .
```

Running `pip list` shows that the module successfully installed:

```
visdom (0.1.4, /home/jkarimi91/Projects/visdom)
```

However, when I try to import the module, I receive an import error:

```
$ which python
/home/jkarimi91/Apps/anaconda2/envs/visdom/bin/python
$ python
Python 2.7.13 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:09:15) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import visdom
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named visdom
>>>
```

Comment: Are you not supposed to install packages for Anaconda using `conda?

Comment: Make sure that `/home/jkarimi91/Projects/` is on python path if that is where you want to install `visdom`. You can check `import sys; print sys.path`. It looks like that is completely outside where the conda env is installed.

Comment: @Jmills it is not in my python path. What do you suggest I do correct this; is there a better solution than add the path to my python path? maybe the `-b` flag in pip?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`-t`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption-t) flag is used to tell pip to install the packages into a particular location, however, there actually appears to be an [open issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4390) with `-t` not playing nice with various other flags (and I just confirmed this for the repo in question). Work around this by installing with the git URL syntax, e.g. `pip install git+git://github.com/facebookresearch/visdom.git@master#egg=visdom`

Comment: this would install the repo version no i.e. without my modifications?

Comment: Yes it would, I didn't realize you were modifying it. If you want to modify it and not reinstall it every time and you are working in another project to test it, you can use PYTHONPATH when you run `python`, e.g. `PYTHONPATH=/home/jkarimi91/visdom/ python whatever.py`. It is the `py` folder that is renamed to `visdom` when it is installed, so you can do `import py as visdom` if you choose to use PYTHONPATH like that. But it looks like there is an example usage in the project, so you may just be able to work in the project itself, it really depends on what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Jmills comment, the path `/home/jkarimi91/Projects/` was not in my python path. Also, as noted by [@Jmills answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46517968/3943552), using `-t` does not seem to be a viable option at the moment.

To fix this issue, I did the following:

```
$ pip uninstall visdom
$ pip install .
```

This approach needs to be repeated every time I make a change to the code but at least it works.